# How can I run Win32OLE calls from ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, docker, wine, win32ole

I have some simple sinatra apps that make use of the OTA COM dll for talking to Quality Center.

I want to move those sites into docker images, so I can host them on my docker server.

It occurred to me that theoretically I should be able to get this working with strategic use of wine.

Hint: I remember reading somewhere that to get Win32OLE working in Ruby from linux you can install the windows version of ruby using wine, then run your scripts through the windows version of ruby.

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/88576 says

> i've managed this before.  i installed the one-click installer under
>   crossover office and the used that.  another option is installing
>   msys, compiling ruby under that, and then using that ruby.  in any
>   case you need to install/build **another** ruby under the crossover environment.

and later

> In the end I installed office 2000 with Crossover, then I used the
>   windows installer to install windows ruby into the same bottle as
>   office. Finally I put the following bash script in my /usr/bin directory
>   so I can run my ruby files with '#> wruby some_script.rb'

```
   ==/usr/bin/wruby
   #!/usr/bin/env ruby
   `/opt/cxofficebeta/bin/wine --bottle myBottle --cx-app ruby.exe #{ARGV.join(" ")}`
```

I know nothing about Wine or crossover or bottles(?), so I'm out of my depth.

How would I do this? What would a Dockerfile I could use as a base image look like?

Note: I found some docker images that claim to install wine (which may make a good starting point)

- https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ambakshi/wine-x11-vcpython27/
- https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/monokrome/wine/
- https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/yantis/wine/

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=430194 talks about getting Win32::OLE working under ubuntu.

Comment: I think you might be hunting a unicorn here.

Comment: I can more than likely do the docker side of things if I can get some instruction on how to use wine to run an MSI and how to use bottles. Maybe I should simplify the question.

Comment: wine msiexec /i xxxxxx.msi should install in wine

Comment: You should look at the Dockerfile in this link,  which dockerizes a Windows software http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1809831

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use a `USER xx` in your Dockerfile as it is important to use a non privileged user in wine. You will find in registry.hub.docker.com several examples of wine with such a user.